# Why is my ball flashing?

Tags: wizorb

I noticed that when the orb has bounced around for a while without breaking any blocks it'll start flashing. When it bounce off the wand again the flashing will stop, and a chime can be heard. So what is the flashing signify, and what happens when the flashing ball bounce off my paddle?

Comment: I somehow misinterpreted the title.... :P...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are about to regenerate mana. This happens when your ball bounces around enough times (seven?) without hitting a brick. This lets you simply blast that last brick out of the way yourself.